# Cannot redirect to a different endpoint in the server side [ExpressJS]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, routes, fetch

I am having trouble redirecting to a different endpoint. I want after a registration, the user gets redirected from /register to /login. I am using Fetch to send the data from the form, with POST, and receiving it on the server.

My code is as follows:

**This is the code on the client-side**

```
    // Activate the register function, when clicking on the register button
    document.querySelector("#register_button").addEventListener("click", registerDone);

    function registerDone(event){
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behaviour of the form

      // Retrieve the information from the input fields
      const user = {
        name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        username: document.getElementById("username").value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
  };
      // define the options for the post method
      const options = {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(user)
    };
    // send to /register and retrieve the response
    fetch("/register", options).then(response => response.json()).
    then(data => console.log("Success")).
    catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

**Here is my register.js file on the server-side**

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 13); // hashing the password, 13 saltrounds

        await User.create({
            name : req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPass
        });
        res.redirect('/login'); 
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server error Occured");
    }
// res.redirect('/login'); 
});
```

**And here is where I'm using the /register endpoint in app.js**

```
/*  Routes & reference files */
app.use("/", require("./routes/index")); // require indexjs file
app.use("/register", require("./routes/register")); // require register file
app.use("/login", require("./routes/login")); // require login file
```

**What I have tried**

- Googling and searching for a relative problem
- Changing the placeholders in the app.js file to "/" and adding register and login to the routes in the files. Didn't work.
- Redirecting to an actual page, to see if the redirect will work, just got an okay response, with no redirection.
- Deleting node_modules and installing them again

**P.S** I'm getting a 304 that everything is okay and the path that should be redirected is localhost:300/login ( I can upload a picture if required ).

**P.S 2** I apologise in advance if this question is similar to others. If there is an answer already, would appreciate to see it.

**What I get:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcEUa.png)

Comment: code should be 301 or 302 as for redirection

Comment: You need to clear your browser cache, to solve this issue

Comment: @JustRaman have tried it, it says that it is 301 or 302, but the page still stays on /register. I get the localhost:3000/login in the network tab with a 304 and clicking on it, redirects me to the /login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting 304 in the console that means browser caching your response.

```js
const options = {
        method:"POST",
        redirect: 'follow',  //<<<---- add this to option to follow redirection 
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

fetch("/register", options)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.info(err + " url: " + url);
    });


// also in your server code. disable last modified date so it will no longer give you 304

app.disable('etag');
```

Comment: Tried Ctrl + F5, clearing the cache and adding your suggested answer in the code. Still getting the same result sadly...

Comment: if the browser is not redirecting try redirect from js. i have updated the answer for that

Comment: Yup, giving it the url did the job and now works. But, I'm still puzzled why it doesn't want to redirect, because I have done a similar operation in the server with redirect and worked fine...anyway, thank you for the help !

Comment: in my last edit, I made a mistake, I mentioned redirect: 'follow' but I didn't use it. can you check now without the `then` block it should redirect without `window.location`

Comment: I get a response 200 on the /login page in the network tab, but the page doesn't display/redirect me.

Comment: response code with 301,302,303,307,308 are only redirected so make sure you send one of them.

Comment: I have added a image link in the bottom of my post, you can check the image and see.